# adding a captcha to guestbook submission form

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to add a captcha to my guestbook submission form but cannot get the if(($_POST['code']) == ($_SESSION['code'])) statement to work. Please see code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if ($_POST['postbtn']){
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $comment = strip_tags($_POST['comment']);
    if(($_POST['code']) == ($_SESSION['code'])) { 
    $code = strip_tags($_POST['code']);
    }

    if($name && $email && $comment && $code){

    $time = date("h:i A");
    $date = date("F d, Y");
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    // add to the database
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES (
        '', '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$time', '$date', '$ip'
    )");

    echo "Your post has been added.";
    }
    else
        echo"You did not enter in all the required info.";
}

echo "<form action='./index.php' method='post'>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='name' style='width: 200px;' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='email' style='width: 200px;' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Comment:</td>
    <td><textarea name='comment' style='width: 197.5px; height: 50px;'> 
   </textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src='captcha.php?'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='code' style='width: 200px;' /></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='postbtn' value='Post' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>";
```

Comment: missing `session_start()` at  guess

Answer (score 0):

Can you try echo on both $_POST['code']  and $_SESSION['code'] so that you can debug it and see if you are getting the values correctly? I don't think you are getting them right. if not just add up a complete scenario here with proper field names and values.